# How to assign start weights for neural net package in r

Tags: r

I am trying to assign start weights in the neuralnet() function of the neuralnet package of r.

```
set.seed(111)
neuralModel <- neuralnet(medv ~ crim+zn, hidden = 1, startweights = c(8,5), train_data)
```

But the output says

> Warning message: some weights were randomly generated, because
>   'startweights' did not contain  enough values

and its assigning random weights to the hidden layer neuron. My training data set have 500 rows. Should I assign 500 weights?

Answer (score 2):

You need to assign five values in the the startweights vector since you have two inputs, two biases and one intercept to the hidden layer. plot your model without assign startweights to get a clearer picture of how many weights are involved. In the plot you can see a weight for each 'edge' (input) until you reach the output

Plot of a neuralnet model with 2 input and 1 hidden layer:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gwpiG.png)